# Quitting VLC processes while streaming

Tags: windows, streaming, directshow, vlc

I have two programs that start a VLC instance through the command line.
One streams video, the other streams audio, both from `dshow://`

When I ask the programs to stop recording and quit VLC, even though both instances quit, the second one always leaves the process running in the background.
Now, I can forcefully kill it, but that would mean my recording is somehow not released and stays corrupted, and I don't want that.

I've tried several quitting methods:

1. Calling `CTRL+Q` (I have it set as the quit Global HotKey)
2. `taskkill /PID xxx` on cmd.exe
3. Adding `vlc://quit` to the end of my command line and calling next (I have `ALT+N` set as the next Global HotKey)
4. Calling stop (again through HotKeys) and then quit.

None of these seems to work. Any ideas?

I'm running Windows 7 x64, and VLC 2.2.2 (I tried both 32 and 64 bit)

Answer (score 1):

So I know this is two years later but I think this may help people. Like you I searched everywhere with nothing working until I tried this:

If nothing works try using the option `--ignore-config` at the beginning after `vlc` in addition to `http://quit` at the end

and it finally worked

Hope some one finds this useful